# PHP Unable to fetch the Cloumn Name from my sql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch Data from my sql Query but I am getting the wrong data So can anyone tell me how to do it correctly.

Here Is my code

```
$result = mysql_query("select
       CONCAT_WS(',',
                 (case when Q1 is not null then 'Q1' else '' end),
                 (case when Q2 is not null then 'Q2' else '' end),
                 (case when Q3 is not null then 'Q3' else '' end),
                 (case when Q4 is not null then 'Q4' else '' end),
                 (case when Q5 is not null then 'Q5' else '' end),
                 (case when Q6 is not null then 'Q6' else '' end),
                 (case when Q7 is not null then 'Q7' else '' end),
                 (case when Q8 is not null then 'Q8' else '' end),
                 (case when Q9 is not null then 'Q9' else '' end)
                ) as NonNullColumns
from $day
where `user` = '$user'") or die(mysql_error());
//echo $result;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 1) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["Q"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $qnumber = array();
        $qns= array();
        $qnumber["Q".$i] = $row["$Q"];
            $i = $i + 1;
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["Q"], $qnumber);
 }
}
```

I am getting the following Output from my SQl query

```
NonNullColumns
Q1,Q2,Q3,,,,,,
Q1,Q2,Q3,,,,,,
Q1,Q2,Q3,,,,,,
Q1,Q2,Q3,,,,,,
Q1,Q2,Q3,,,,,,
Q1,Q2,Q3,,,,,,
```

I need to fetch the values Q1, Q2,Q3 from my SQl query output but I am able to fetch

```
{"Q":[{"Q":null},{"Q1":null},{"Q2":null},{"Q3":null},{"Q4":null},{"Q5":null}],"success":1}
```

So Can any one tell me how to obtain the followig output

```
{"Q":[{Q1},{Q2},{Q3}],"success":1}
```

Comment: where is the closing bracket of while loop?

Comment: if you want only Q1 Q2 Q3 why are you querying for all Q1 to Q9?

Comment: Because I want only not null coloumns. So here I have Q1,Q2,Q3 as not null coloumns

Answer (score 0):

You have only one column as you've concatenated all data.
So instead of refering to `$row["$Q"]` you have to `explode(',', $row['NonNullColumns'])` and add non-empty string to the array